# How to get a selected range of text from a UITextView or UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, nsattributedstring, uitextrange

I am trying to get the selected range of text from a UITextView (and or UITextField) so that I can edit the selected text, or modify an attributed string. The method below is triggered when I make a selection, but the code in the method returns null values.

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {

    UITextRange *selectedRange = [textField selectedTextRange];

    NSLog(@"Start: %@ <> End: %@", selectedRange.start, selectedRange.end);

}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can try this,

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {

   UITextRange *selectedRange = [textView selectedTextRange];
   NSString *selectedText = [textView textInRange:selectedRange];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift**

First get the selected text range, and then use that range to get the actual text:

```
if let textRange = myTextView.selectedTextRange {

    let selectedText = myTextView.text(in: textRange)

    // ...
}
```

**Notes:**

- Selecting text from a `UITextField` is done in the same way.
- The range is a `UITextRange`, not an `NSRange`. This allows for proper selection of things like emoji and extended grapheme clusters. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35193481/3681880) for related details about this.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.0**

here is how I selecte file name `Panda` from `Panda.txt`

```swift
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // if textField.text is `Panda.txt`, offset will be 3
    let offset = String(textField.text!.split(separator: ".").last!).length
    let from = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: 0)
    let to = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument,
                                offset:textField.text!.length - (offset+1) )
    //now `Panda` will be selected
    textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: from!, to: to!)
    //note: unwrap with `!` is not recommended, text here is 100% not null,so it's safe
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.1**

In your `UITextView` Extension put the below code in a function, and use that in your controller:
You can call this method with your textView instance in the SelectionDidChange delegate method from your view-Controller. Better to wrap this function call with condition `textView.selectedRange.length > 0`, to get some text...

```
  let begin = self.beginningOfDocument
  let start = self.position(from: begin, offset: selectedRange.location)
  let end = self.position(from: position(from: start!, offset: 0)!, offset: selectedRange.length)
  let txtRange = self.textRange(from: start!, to: end!)

  let txt = self.text(in: txtRange!)
  print("Sel Text is \(String(describing: txt))")
```

We can not use the optional binding to store the selected range, instead you can declare an optional for nsrange type, then use the if- let ... thing.

`TextInputComponent` has a property to get the selected text range.

```
let range = textView.selectedRange
```

Then you can use `range.location`, `range.length` values to change attributes of text in the container, etc...