# How to create range in Swift?

Tags: swift, range

In Objective-c we create range by using NSRange

```
NSRange range;
```

So how to create range in Swift?

Comment: What do you need the range for? Swift strings use `Range<String.Index>`, but sometimes it is necessary to work with `NSString` and `NSRange`, so some more context would be useful. – But have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language.

Answer (score 302, accepted):

*Updated for Swift 4*

Swift ranges are more complex than `NSRange`, and they didn't get any easier in Swift 3. If you want to try to understand the reasoning behind some of this complexity, read [this](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/09/swift-3-ranges/) and [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md). I'll just show you how to create them and when you might use them.

## Closed Ranges:  `a...b`

This [range operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) creates a Swift range which includes both element `a` *and* element `b`, even if `b` is the maximum possible value for a type (like `Int.max`). There are two different types of closed ranges: `ClosedRange` and `CountableClosedRange`.

#### 1. `ClosedRange`

The elements of all ranges in Swift are comparable (ie, they conform to the Comparable protocol). That allows you to access the elements in the range from a collection. Here is an example:

```
let myRange: ClosedRange = 1...3

let myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
myArray[myRange] // ["b", "c", "d"]
```

However, a `ClosedRange` is not countable (ie, it does not conform to the Sequence protocol). That means you can't iterate over the elements with a `for` loop. For that you need the `CountableClosedRange`.

#### 2. `CountableClosedRange`

This is similar to the last one except now the range can also be iterated over.

```
let myRange: CountableClosedRange = 1...3

let myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
myArray[myRange] // ["b", "c", "d"]

for index in myRange {
    print(myArray[index])
}
```

## Half-Open Ranges: `a..<b`

This range operator includes element `a` but *not* element `b`. Like above, there are two different types of half-open ranges: `Range` and `CountableRange`.

#### 1. `Range`

As with `ClosedRange`, you can access the elements of a collection with a `Range`. Example:

```
let myRange: Range = 1..<3

let myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
myArray[myRange] // ["b", "c"]
```

Again, though, you cannot iterate over a `Range` because it is only comparable, not stridable.

#### 2. `CountableRange`

A `CountableRange` allows iteration.

```
let myRange: CountableRange = 1..<3

let myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
myArray[myRange] // ["b", "c"]

for index in myRange {
    print(myArray[index])
}
```

## NSRange

You can (must) still use `NSRange` at times in Swift (when making [attributed strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32269975/3681880), for example), so it is helpful to know how to make one.

```
let myNSRange = NSRange(location: 3, length: 2)
```

Note that this is location and *length*, not start index and end index. The example here is similar in meaning to the Swift range `3..<5`. However, since the types are different, they are not interchangeable.

## Ranges with Strings

The `...` and `..<` range operators are a shorthand way of creating ranges. For example:

```
let myRange = 1..<3
```

The long hand way to create the same range would be

```
let myRange = CountableRange<Int>(uncheckedBounds: (lower: 1, upper: 3)) // 1..<3
```

You can see that the index type here is `Int`. That doesn't work for `String`, though, because Strings are made of Characters and not all characters are the same size. (Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) for more info.) An emoji like , for example, takes more space than the letter "b".

**Problem with NSRange**

Try experimenting with `NSRange` and an `NSString` with emoji and you'll see what I mean. Headache.

```
let myNSRange = NSRange(location: 1, length: 3)

let myNSString: NSString = "abcde"
myNSString.substring(with: myNSRange) // "bcd"

let myNSString2: NSString = "acde"
myNSString2.substring(with: myNSRange) // "c"    Where is the "d"!?
```

The smiley face takes two UTF-16 code units to store, so it gives the unexpected result of not including the "d".

**Swift Solution**

Because of this, with Swift Strings you use `Range<String.Index>`, not `Range<Int>`. The String Index is calculated based on a particular string so that it knows if there are any emoji or extended grapheme clusters.

Example

```
var myString = "abcde"
let start = myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let end = myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
let myRange = start..<end
myString[myRange] // "bcd"

myString = "acde"
let start2 = myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let end2 = myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
let myRange2 = start2..<end2
myString[myRange2] // "cd"
```

## One-sided Ranges: `a...` and `...b` and `..<b`

In Swift 4 things were simplified a bit. Whenever the starting or ending point of a range can be inferred, you can leave it off.

**Int**

You can use one-sided integer ranges to iterate over collections. Here are some examples from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html).

```
// iterate from index 2 to the end of the array
for name in names[2...] {
    print(name)
}

// iterate from the beginning of the array to index 2
for name in names[...2] {
    print(name)
}

// iterate from the beginning of the array up to but not including index 2
for name in names[..<2] {
    print(name)
}

// the range from negative infinity to 5. You can't iterate forward
// over this because the starting point in unknown.
let range = ...5
range.contains(7)   // false
range.contains(4)   // true
range.contains(-1)  // true

// You can iterate over this but it will be an infinate loop 
// so you have to break out at some point.
let range = 5...
```

**String**

This also works with String ranges. If you are making a range with `str.startIndex` or `str.endIndex` at one end, you can leave it off. The compiler will infer it.

Given

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)

let myRange = ..<index    // Hello
```

You can go from the index to str.endIndex by using `...`

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
let index = str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -10)
let myRange = index...        // playground
```

## See also:

- [How does String.Index work in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676940/3681880)
- [How does String substring work in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39677331/3681880)

**Notes**

- You can't use a range you created with one string on a different string.
- As you can see, String ranges are a pain in Swift, but they do make it possibly to deal better with emoji and other Unicode scalars.

## Further Study

- [String Range examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring-swift)
- [Range Operator documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)
- [Strings and Characters documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

Comment: My comment pertains to the "Problem with NSRange" subsection. `NSString` internally stores its characters in UTF-16 encoding. A full unicode scalar is 21-bit. The grinning face character (`U+1F600`) cannot be stored in a single 16-bit code unit, so it's spread over 2. `NSRange` counts based on 16-bit code units. In this example, 3 code units happen to represent only 2 characters

Answer (score 25):

**Xcode 8 beta 2 • Swift 3**

```
let myString = "Hello World"
let myRange = myString.startIndex..<myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
let mySubString = myString.substring(with: myRange)   // Hello
```

---

**Xcode 7 • Swift 2.0**

```
let myString = "Hello World"
let myRange = Range<String.Index>(start: myString.startIndex, end: myString.startIndex.advancedBy(5))

let mySubString = myString.substringWithRange(myRange)   // Hello
```

or simply

```
let myString = "Hello World"
let myRange = myString.startIndex..<myString.startIndex.advancedBy(5)
let mySubString = myString.substringWithRange(myRange)   // Hello
```

Answer (score 5):

I find it surprising that, even in Swift 4, there's still no simple native way to express a String range using Int. The only String methods that let you supply an Int as a way of obtaining a substring by range are `prefix` and `suffix`.

It is useful to have on hand some conversion utilities, so that we can talk like NSRange when speaking to a String. Here's a utility that takes a location and length, just like NSRange, and returns a `Range<String.Index>`:

```
func range(_ start:Int, _ length:Int) -> Range<String.Index> {
    let i = self.index(start >= 0 ? self.startIndex : self.endIndex,
        offsetBy: start)
    let j = self.index(i, offsetBy: length)
    return i..<j
}
```

For example, `"hello".range(0,1)"` is the `Range<String.Index>` embracing the first character of `"hello"`. As a bonus, I've allowed negative locations: `"hello".range(-1,1)"` is the `Range<String.Index>` embracing the last character of `"hello"`.

It is useful also to convert a `Range<String.Index>` to an NSRange, for those moments when you have to talk to Cocoa (for example, in dealing with NSAttributedString attribute ranges). Swift 4 provides a native way to do that:

```
let nsrange = NSRange(range, in:s) // where s is the string
```

We can thus write another utility where we go directly from a String location and length to an NSRange:

```
extension String {
    func nsRange(_ start:Int, _ length:Int) -> NSRange {
        return NSRange(self.range(start,length), in:self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
var start = str.startIndex // Start at the string's start index
var end = advance(str.startIndex, 5) // Take start index and advance 5 characters forward
var range: Range<String.Index> = Range<String.Index>(start: start,end: end)

let firstFiveDigit =  str.substringWithRange(range)

print(firstFiveDigit)
```

**Output :** Hello

Comment: I see they have "Range" Datatype. So how can I use it?

Comment: @vichhai Can you elaborate more where you want to use ?

Comment: Like in objective c: 
NSRange range;

Answer (score 2):

> (1..<10)

returns...

> Range = 1..<10

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone want to create NSRange object can create as:

```
let range: NSRange = NSRange.init(location: 0, length: 5)
```

this will create range with position 0 and length 5

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
let nsRange = NSRange(location: someInt, length: someInt)
```

as in

```
let myNSString = bigTOTPCode as NSString //12345678
let firstDigit = myNSString.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 1)) //1
let secondDigit = myNSString.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 1, length: 1)) //2
let thirdDigit = myNSString.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 2, length: 4)) //3456
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the following extension:

```
extension String {
    func substring(from from:Int, to:Int) -> String? {
        if from<to && from>=0 && to<self.characters.count {
            let rng = self.startIndex.advancedBy(from)..<self.startIndex.advancedBy(to)
            return self.substringWithRange(rng)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

example of use:

```
print("abcde".substring(from: 1, to: 10)) //nil
print("abcde".substring(from: 2, to: 4))  //Optional("cd")
print("abcde".substring(from: 1, to: 0))  //nil
print("abcde".substring(from: 1, to: 1))  //nil
print("abcde".substring(from: -1, to: 1)) //nil
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func replace(input: String, start: Int,lenght: Int, newChar: Character) -> String {
    var chars = Array(input.characters)

    for i in start...lenght {
        guard i < input.characters.count else{
            break
        }
        chars[i] = newChar
    }
    return String(chars)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to do this:

```
print("Hello"[1...3])
// out: Error
```

But unfortunately, I can't write a subscript of my own because the loathed one takes up the name space.

We can do this however:

```
print("Hello"[range: 1...3])
// out: ell
```

Just add this to your project:

```
extension String {
    subscript(range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> String {
        get {
            let start = String.Index(utf16Offset: range.lowerBound, in: self)
            let end = String.Index(utf16Offset: range.upperBound, in: self)
            return String(self[start...end])
        }
    }
}
```