# Value of type 'String' has no member 'substringToIndex'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but all I'm trying to do is get a substring from a string. I'm messing around in a playground, and my code is only three lines long lines long, I declare a string, get an index, then try and get a substring from it, and I get this error. This is all I have for my code...

```
var name = "Stephen"
var index = name.startIndex.advancedBy(3)
var substring = name.substringToIndex(index)
```

Am I doing this wrong? I don't see any other ways to get a substring from a string.

In an unrelated question, if I want to grab a substring from a string between indices 2 and 5 how would I go about that in Swift 2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since `substringToIndex` is defined into the `Foundation` module, you need to add

```
import Foundation
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's always the simplest things that you miss... I will accept your answer in 6 minutes! Do you know how I would grab a substring that doesn't start the beginning?

Comment: I had the same issue some time ago ;-)

Answer (score 14):

For anyone who is searching for Swift 3 solution:

```
var name = "Stephen"
var index = name.index(name.startIndex, offsetBy:3)
var substring = name.substring(to:index)
```

Answer (score 0):

about the unrelated question..

```
var name = "Stephen"
var substring = name.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: name.startIndex.advancedBy(3),end: name.startIndex.advancedBy(5)))
```

related answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30094120/2000162)