# 'init(start:end:)' is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3. Use the '..<' operator

Tags: swift, xcode7.3

I'm using the following code:

```
var continousDigitsRange:Range<Int> = Range<Int>(start: 0, end: 0)
```

Since update to Xcode 7.3 (Swift 2.2) I got the following hint:

> 'init(start:end:)' is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3. Use
>   the '..<' operator.

For me is not clear how to "translate" it correctly with "using the '..<' operator.

Comment: for item in 0 ..< items { } for item in 0 ... 100 { }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30094120/2303865

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You should simply write

```
var continousDigitsRange1:Range<Int> = 0..<0
```

or if you want to go even simpler

```
var continousDigitsRange = 0..<0
```

Answer (score 35):

Also worth noting, to `substringWithRange` a String, you can now use

```
let theString = "Hello, how are you"
let range = theString.startIndex.advancedBy(start) ..< theString.startIndex.advancedBy(end)
theString.substringWithRange(range)
```

Comment: One small thing is that if you are counting from the end of the string, use endIndex instead of start like bellow:
'let range = theString.startIndex.advancedBy(start) ..< theString.endIndex.advancedBy(end)'

Answer (score 8):

> The closed range operator `(a...b)` defines a range that runs from a
>   to b, and includes the values a and b. The value of a must not be
>   greater than b.
>
> The half-open range operator `(a..<b)` defines a range that runs from a
>   to b, but does not include b. It is said to be half-open because it
>   contains its first value, but not its final value. As with the closed
>   range operator, the value of a must not be greater than b. If the
>   value of a is equal to b, then the resulting range will be empty.

[The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2) - Basic Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

```
var continousDigitsRange:Range<Int> = Range<Int>(start: 0, end: 0)
--to--
var continousDigitsRange:Range<Int> = 0..<0
```

Comment: Ahh, yeah good point, switched it up - wanted to illustrate the range options in swift.

Comment: What ends up in continuousDigitsRange? Looks like a nil to me. What use could this range be put to? I'm trying to learn too!

Answer (score 2):

to show bmichotte's answer in full...

```
let theString = "Hello, how are you today my friend"
    let start = 3
    let end = 15
    let range = theString.startIndex.advancedBy(start) ..< theString.startIndex.advancedBy(end)
    let p = theString.substringWithRange(range)
    print("this is the middle bit>\(p)<")
```

this produces this is the middle bit>lo, how are <

Answer (score 1):

Adding some points with reference to swift 3.0

//Countable Range Example.

`let range1 = 0..<5`

Countable Closed Range Example

```
let range2 = 0...5
```

//Range from bounds

```
let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (range1.lowerBound,range1.upperBound))
```

//To get the distance from substringRange.

```
let str = "Hello, how are you"
let substringRange = str.characters.indices
```

// Below Swift 3.0

```
let length = substringRange.distance(from: substringRange.startIndex, to: substringRange.endIndex)
```

//For Swift 3.0

```
let length2 = str.distance(from: substringRange.startIndex, to: substringRange.endIndex)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have always had a function to get the substring range of a string. Here is my updated function for Swift 3:

```
func getSubStringRange(fullString: String, fromIndex: Int, subStringSize: Int) -> Range<String.Index> {
    let startIndex = fullString.characters.index(fullString.startIndex, offsetBy: fromIndex)
    let endIndex = fullString.characters.index(startIndex, offsetBy: subStringSize)

    let subStringRange = startIndex..<endIndex

    return subStringRange
}
```

The function is pretty self explanatory - You pass in a string(fullString), the index of that string where the substring starts(fromIndex) and how big the subString is(subStringSize).

Example:

```
let greeting = "Hi, my name is Nathaniel"
let getName = greeting[getSubStringRange(fullString: greeting, fromIndex: 15, subStringSize: 9)]

print("Name: \(getName)")
```

-> Prints: "Name: Nathaniel"

Comment: Doesn't compile with Swift 3. There is no closing `)` after `subStringSize: Int `

Comment: At the `endIndex` property you missed `fullString.` before `startIndex`, so the correct would be: `let endIndex = fullString.characters.index(fullString.startIndex, offsetBy: subStringSize)`

Comment: Thanks guys. I must have been asleep when I typed that! I had to manually type the whole lot rather than a copy / paste directly from my code as I was on a Windows PC when posting!