# Is this deprecated in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am using the Range method which worked on swift 2, but after updating to swift 3 I get this error. My guess is that it was deprecated.[image]

```
let range = Range<String.Index>(start: numbers.startIndex, end: numbers.endIndex)
```

Comment: Instead of guessing, read the documentation. All the changes are explained.

Comment: Could you please provide the link

Comment: Everything is here: https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/ Specifically, for this question: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/range

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157777/initstartend-is-deprecated-it-will-be-removed-in-swift-3-use-the-o

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik that did the trick

Comment: @manatee - your problem is resolved or not

Comment: endIndex property is position after last character in a String, as a result it is not valid argument to a string's subscript. Hence startIndex..<endIndex instead of startIndex...endIndex

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes it is resolved.

Comment: @manatee - happy to hear bro