# Creating closed Range in Swift 3 not working

Tags: ios, swift3

Can anyone tell me why the code below works in Swift 2, but somehow breaks in Swift 3?

```
let range: Range = 0...2
```

However it can simply be fixed by doing this

```
let range: Range = 0..<3
```

Anyone knows what is the reason behind this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157777/initstartend-is-deprecated-it-will-be-removed-in-swift-3-use-the-o

Comment: A very good example for the nonsense of explicit type annotations. If the compiler needs help it will tell you (e.g. *ambiguous use of something...*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operators `...` and `..<` used to produce the same type, `Range`, in Swift 2.x. Now they produce different types ([migration guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/)):

- `Range`
- `CountableRange`
- `ClosedRange`
- `CountableClosedRange`

Changing the type in the first assignment to `ClosedRange` should fix the problem. Better yet, let Swift infer the type for you:

```
let range = 0...2
```