# count, utf8.count, utf16.count returns different results

Tags: swift

I wonder why I am getting different results in each of the following lines

```
let spain = "España"
print (spain.count) -- return 6
print (spain.utf8.count) -- return 7
print (spain.utf16.count) -- return 6
print (spain.utf8CString.count) -- return 8
```

Comment: Why do you expect them to be the same? They are different encodings.

Comment: Have a look at "Unicode Representations of Strings" in https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html

Comment: Not sure what you're using the count for, but if it's for something like figuring out a range, you may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35193481/4475605

Answer (score 1):

The `count` in `String` and in `String.UTF8View`, `String.UTF16View` etc are different because their way of storage is different although they are all collections. `String` stores them in a collection of characters, so each item in the collection represents one character. However, in other encodings, they are stored in a collection of that encoding's code units. Some special characters (like ñ) have to be stored in two units. For ñ, it is `0xC3 0xB1` in UTF8 while it is `0x00F1` in UTF16, so you can see that there is one more item in the UTF8 encoding than UTF16. You cannot get the number of characters accurately with `count` unless you are using the base `String`.