# Cannot convert value of type 'ClosedRange<Int>' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'

Tags: swift, type-conversion, swiftui

I have this code:

```
VStack {
    ForEach(0...2) { i in
        HStack {
            ForEach(0...2) { j in
                Text("test")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the error

> Cannot convert value of type 'ClosedRange' to expected argument
> type 'Range'

on both `ForEach` calls.

I've seen threads on this error and kind of get it a bit on how the range thing works but not really. I'm wondering how to fix this error.

Comment: `ForEach(0..<3)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create range in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093688/how-to-create-range-in-swift)

Comment: That is strange. I do not encounter compiler error, except getting warning from IDE "Non-constant range: argument must be an integer literal". But the code is still workable. Are you using XCode 15?

Answer (score 31):

It is possible to use `ClosedRange` but with different `ForEach` constructor, providing `id`, like

```
    VStack {
        ForEach(0...2, id: \.self) { i in
            HStack {
                ForEach(0...2, id: \.self) { j in
                    Text("test")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `id: \.self` is a mistake that leads to memory leaks, the docs state `id` needs to be a property of the data, it can't be the data itself.

Comment: @malhal can you provide a link to the docs stating that? Apple in fact use `\.self` in many of their examples, for example: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/menuindicator(_:)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:id:content:)-82hm4 "id - The key path to the provided data’s identifier." If you decompile ForEach in Hopper you'll see the range init is a very different code path from the others.

Comment: @malhal The documentation for ForEach does not explicitly prohibit `id: \.self` and its been widely used. I'm not used to do decompiling/disassembling, so it would be difficult for me to check. Are you sure it leads to memory leaks? In every case or just with `ClosedRange`?

Answer (score 20):

You can use `..<` instead of `...` for range to be of type `Range<Index>` instead of `ClosedRange<Index>`

```
 VStack {
        ForEach(0..<2) { i in
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<2) { j in
                    Text("test")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't get why `ForEach` is not overloaded for `ClosedRange` too. Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

It works if you extend the `ForEach` with a simple helper initializer like:

```
extension ForEach where Data == Range<Int>, ID == Int, Content : View {
    public init(_ range: ClosedRange<Int>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content) {
        self.init(range.lowerBound..<(range.upperBound+1), id: \.self, content: content)
    }
}
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Mhh... I wouldn't like to introduce such a helper. It's a shame that SwiftUI doesn't provide that. Dont' see a reason why.

Comment: @WilliMentzel it is fine to define helpers. Don't forget Swift didn't have the `toggle` function [until Swift v4.2](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0199-bool-toggle.md) and it was as simple as `self = !self` :)