# SwiftUI / Xcode: ForEach closed range vs half open range - error with Text function. Why the difference?

Tags: swiftui, foreach

I have an old pascal and C background, and recently started to learn Swift.
I have encountered an error beyond my common sense.

Following code works fine.

[click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q78Ux.png)

```
ForEach(0..<12) { word in
    Text(String(word))
}
```

but as soon as ForEach changes from ..< to ...
it gives an error of
Cannot convert value of type 'ClosedRange' to expected argument type 'Range'

[click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCKB1.png)

```
ForEach(0...12) { word in
    Text(String(word))
}
```

Now what is the mechanism/reason behind this?
With tan old coding background, it is difficult to grasp why.
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: That is strange. I do not encounter compiler error, except getting warning from IDE "Non-constant range: argument must be an integer literal". But the code is still workable. Are you using XCode 15?

Answer (score 1):

According to your examples, there are two types of range.

1. The first one is half-open range. Create ranges excluding the final element.

```swift
let half = 0..<5
//Range<Int>
```

2. The second one is closed range. Create ranges including the final element.

```swift
let closed = 0...5
//ClosedRange<Int>
```

And `ForEach` in SwiftUI takes `Range` as it's parameter so that's why you got an error. It's different variables, such as: Float vs Double, Int vs Float, etc. You can see in document below.

> public init(_ data: Range, @TableRowBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content) where Data == Range, ID == Int, V == Content.TableRowValue

Answer (score 0):

You should define the id for the `ClosedRange<Int>`

```
ForEach(0...12, id: \.self) { word in
    Text(String(word))
}
```

Here I've used the number itself as the identifier.

You can also make it work by implementing a simple extension on the `ForEach` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77445993/5623035)